# Python scheduler добавление задач

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

С веб-формы в на сервер будет закидываться задача на разное время выполнения.

Но дело в том,что при запуске первой задачи, вторая не запускается.

Пример кода (словарь d приведен как пример входных данных):

```
def test_run_func_schedule(data):
    print('test_run_func_schedule:',data)



def test_send_func_schedule(data):
    d= {'vm1': 2, 'vm2': 4, 'vm3': 8}

    for k,v in d.items():
        schedule.every(v).seconds.do(lambda: test_run_func_schedule(k)).tag('second-tasks', 'VM_'+k)
        while 1:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

На консоль выводит только vm1. Остальные не выводит. Как сделать ,чтою задачи остальные так же выполнялись?

Comment: Для начала код написать как в документаций https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Поправьте отступы так чтобы они были именно так как они у вас в коде, чтобы было понятно, что проблема не в них.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл `while` не должен быть внутри цикла `for`. Сначала должен до конца выполниться цикл `for`, в котором у вас добавляются задачи, а потом уже запуститься бесконечный цикл обработки событий. Сейчас у вас добавляется ровно одна задача, а потом сразу запускается бесконечный цикл, остальные задачи не добавляются (очевидно, потому что бесконечный цикл никогда не заканчивается).

Кроме того, лябмда получает значение `k` из глобальной переменной `k` (последнее значение), а не значение, которое было на момент создания лямбды.

Нужно или передавать через значение параметра по-умолчанию:

```
lambda key=k: test_run_func_schedule(key)
```

Или использовать `functools.partial` ("частичное применение функции к параметрам", на самом деле создание новой функции, которая при вызове предзаполняет некоторые параметры переданной функции):

```
functools.partial(test_run_func_schedule, k)
```

Так должно работать:

```
import schedule
import time
from functools import partial

def test_run_func_schedule(data):
    print('test_run_func_schedule:',data)

d= {'vm1': 2, 'vm2': 4, 'vm3': 8}

for k,v in d.items():
    schedule.every(v).seconds.do(partial(test_run_func_schedule, k)).tag('second-tasks', 'VM_'+k)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: В таком случае будет выводиться только vm3

Comment: @Guamokolatokint еще одну проблему не увидел сразу, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Короче, разобрался.
Использовал apscheduler

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    for k,v in d.items():
    sched.add_job(test_run_func_schedule, 'interval', [k], seconds=v)
sched.start()
```

Comment: Это по сути то же самое, что и в моем ответе: сначала все задачи планируются, а потом уже запускается их обработка. `sched.start()` внутри содержит что-то похожее на цикл `while True`.